# How to change ClamAV update repo? Error: "Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!"

Tags: debian, clamav

I am running a Debian 11 bullseye server and every now and then clamav tells me that I am not using the current version. :

```
The ClamAV update process was started 25 time(s)
 
 Last ClamAV update process started at Sun Oct 29 23:00:08 2023
 
 Last Status:
    WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
    WARNING: Local version: 0.103.10 Recommended version: 0.103.11
    DON'T PANIC! Read https://docs.clamav.net/manual/Installing.html
    daily.cld database is up-to-date (version: 27076, sigs: 2045146, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
    main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
    bytecode.cld database is up-to-date (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
 
 Local version: 0.103.10 Recommended version: 0.103.11
 Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
```

Can I add a more recent repo for clamav to get the latest version faster?
Debian takes a few weeks till months to distribute the current ClamAV version packages. Also I don't want to install it manually all the time, because the process is kinda annoying.

Comment: Look at the [release notes](https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/clamav/releases/tag/clamav-0.103.11). That is 2 windows fixes, and one more for the optional `libclamunrar` library which Debian, if at all, ships separately from the mostly GPL software, because it is not free software. Unless you were using that, you might as well ignore that release.

Comment: It's not the first time this occurs to me. I was annoyed by the error messages I get every time. This was my idea of fixing this and always be on the newest version.

Comment: Still getting this error. Reinstalling clamav won't solve it. There even is a bug report for this in the bugtracker. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1060306